# How to display two models data in lavavel blade view selected by with method

Tags: laravel

I have selected data from two models by with() method and now I want to display these Two models' record in view, how can I do this.

$posts=Post::where('slug','=',Str::lower($id))->with('comment')->first();

Comment: `return view('your.view.name', ['posts'=>$posts]);`

Comment: return view('view name')->with(compact('posts'));

Answer (score 1):

In your controller use this

```
$posts=Post::where('slug','=',Str::lower($id))->get();
return view('view.name',compact('posts');
```

Lets try this in your blade

```
@foreach($posts as $val)
  {{$val->comment()->id}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
return view('view.name', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

In view

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
//do something
@endforeach
```